# VSTO Send custom email

Tags: c#, email, outlook, vsto

User create new email, and after click Send button, mail is lost and Add-on create new email with same `TO`,`CC`,`BCC`, `subject`, `Attachment` and `HTMLBody`.

and HTMLBody will be modified via some texts.

My problem is how to access to all values from users new email.

```
 public void SendNewEmail( object Item, ref bool Cancel)
 {
     Outlook.MailItem newMailItem = Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
     newMailItem.To = ;
     newMailItem.Subject = ;
     newMailItem.Attachment = ;
     newMailItem.HTMLBody = ;
     
     newMailItem.Send(); 
  }
```

UPDATE I

Is that correct?

```
public void SendNewEmail(object Item, MailSendType SendType)
    {
        Outlook.MailItem newMailItem = Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        Outlook.MailItem mItem = Item as Outlook.MailItem;
        
        newMailItem.To = mItem.To;
        newMailItem.Subject = mItem.Subject;
        newMailItem.HTMLBody = mItem.HTMLBody;

        newMailItem.Send();
    }

private void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
      SendNewEmail(Item, MailSendType.Normal);  
}
```

Comment: Use : Outlook.MailItem mItem =  Item as Outlook.MailItem;

Comment: @jdweng and what put in ````newMailItem.To = ? ````

Comment: newMailItem.To = mItem.To;

Comment: @jdweng is ````update I```` correct?

Comment: You may need to set the FROM and the Credentials.  Not sure.  Been a long time since I used the Outlook Net Library.